# Интересный тип придаточного предложения

Tags: синтаксис, тип-придаточных

Из известной научно-популярной книги "Занимательная физика" автора Перельмана:

***Это изобретение тем лестнее для ума человеческого, что всецело почерпнуто из этого источника (т. е. из ума).***

Можно много аналогичного сочинить:

Ваша похвала тем для меня приятнее, что вы обычно никого не хвалите, а меня похвалили.

Ваша любовь тем ценнее для Васи, что вы раньше никого не любили.

Вот структура: **тем** + сравнительная степень + придаточное с союзом **что**.

Как думаете, что это за придаточное, если исходить их современных классификаций придаточных предложений? Ближе всего эти предложения к какому типу? Тут можно усмотреть и изъяснительное, и причинное даже.

Comment: В Ваших аналогично сочинённых фразах есть доля манипуляции. Рассуждение ушло в сторону.

Comment: Есть что сказать по делу?

Comment: По Вашему делу: вводите в заблуждение, возможно, что не понимая того.

Comment: Короче, сказать нечего. Понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Это изобретение тем лестнее для ума человеческого, что всецело почерпнуто из этого источника (т. е. из ума).*

Да, конструкция интересна, но сдаётся мне, что она носит разговорный характер (инверсия указательного слова, вместо краткого прилагательного сравнительная степень), если привести её в нормативный литературный вид, то получится: *Это изобретение  лестно для ума человеческого тем, что всецело почерпнуто из этого источника (т. е. из ума).*
 И тогда понятно, что это **придаточное изъяснительное.**

Придаточные изъяснительные относятся к одному слову в главной части – глаголу, краткому прилагательному, наречию, отглагольному существительному со значением речи, мысли, чувства, восприятия. У нас **краткое прилагательное со значением чувства.**

Правда, чаще всего в главной части таких предложений указательное слово  может быть опущено,  придаточное относится к прилагательному.  Однако в некоторых СПП с придаточными изъяснительными **указательное слово в главной части является обязательным компонентом структуры предложения;** напр.: *Всё началось с того, что вернулся отец.* Такие придаточные относятся именно к указательному слову, в качестве которого может выступать только слово то. **Эта особенность сближает такие предложения с местоименно-определительными, использование же союза, а не союзного слова (= который) позволяет отнести их к изъяснительным.**

Изъяснительное придаточное обычно находится за тем словом в главной части, к которому относится - в литературном варианте это соблюдается, в разговорном у нас инверсия, но это допустимо. Книга ведь написана в научно-популярном стиле, там образные разговорные конструкции допустимы, в строгом учебнике математики этого бы не было.

Придаточное изъяснительное занимает позицию, соответствующую дополнению или подлежащему. У нас - дополнению. Тоже соответствует.

И да, согласна, оттенок причины тоже есть, но к придаточным обстоятельственным причины его относить нельзя, союз всё-таки не причинный, а изъяснительный (что), хотя вопрос почему? возможен, но он не основной.